# how to minus quantity in mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

When I'm running the following query with + sign it is adding the values and showing correct result but when I replace + sign with - sign it is still showing the correct result but showing - sign before the result. Why is it displaying - sign in the result?

please help me to fix this issue thanks

> `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE quantity='$quantity'-quantity  ")`

it is showing result like this

```
--------------
 quantity row
--------------
    -5
--------------
```

this is not working perfect

```
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO stock SET date='$date',company='$company',itemname='$itemname',quantity='$quantity',category='$category',signature='$signature' 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE quantity='$quantity'-quantity ")
```

this is working

```
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO stock SET date='$date',company='$company',itemname='$itemname',quantity='$quantity',category='$category',signature='$signature' 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE quantity='$quantity'+quantity ")
```

i m insert to query togetter
this is my complete code but 1st one is working fine but 2nd one have problm

```
         // save the data to the database
          mysql_query("INSERT INTO  recivereturn SET date='$date',company='$company',itemname='$itemname',quantity='$quantity',category='$category',signature='$signature'");

$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO stock SET date='$date',company='$company',itemname='$itemname',quantity='$quantity',category='$category',signature='$signature' 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE quantity=$quantity-quantity ")
```

Comment: You probably want `... UPDATE quantity = quantity - '$quantity'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost certainly doing the subtraction backwards. You probably want to subtract a variable from the current value of the column, not vice versa:

```
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE quantity = quantity - '$quantity'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like

```
"ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE quantity=".$quantity."-quantity ")
```

Like

```
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO stock 
                       SET date='$date',company='$company',itemname='$itemname',quantity='$quantity',
                       category='$category',signature='$signature' 
                       ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE quantity= ".$quantity."+quantity ")
```

Comment: please check the `$quantity`

Comment: @user2938105 Is `quantity row` as you said *"it is showing result like this"* two seperate columns, or are they the same? It's a bit confusing along with using the same word/variable (quantity).

Comment: see my question they are same

Answer (score 0):

Please try once $quantity without quotes.

```
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO stock SET date='$date',company='$company',itemname='$itemname',quantity='$quantity',category='$category',signature='$signature' 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE quantity=$quantity-quantity ");
```

Comment: Did you tried $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO stock SET date='$date',company='$company',itemname='$itemname',quantity='$quantity',category='$category',signature='$signature' 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE quantity=quantity-$quantity");